# Check if a given date is past

Tags: php, date, time

I have a week calendar that holds events, and want that users can't add events for the past days. So I'm tring to use a function like that:

```
if( strtotime($this->day) < time() ){ // date format is YYYY-MM-DD
// date is past 
}else{   
// date is not past
}
```

It seems to works fine, except that it consider today date as a past day. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A timestamp never contains only the date, but is always down to the current second. `strtotime($this->day)` is going to return today's date at `0:00`, while you are comparing it against now, say, `11:12`.

You could use `strtotime("$this->day 12:59:59pm");` (if the format of `$this->day` allows for that) or use *tomorrow*'s timestamp.

Comment: Alternately, use `strtotime($this->day)<time()-24*60*60`.

Answer (score 11):

Simpler ->

```
if(strtotime($this->day) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you too! I was not considering to set today date in time() function!

Comment: strtotime function ... just did a typo .. sorry

Comment: if you want to also account for seconds, add in H:i:s `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtotime($this->day) < mktime(0, 0, 0)){
    // date is past
} else {
    // date is not past
}
```